# httr GET operation unable to access JSON response

Tags: json, r, httr

I am trying to access the JSON response from an API call in my R script. The API call is succesful, and I can view the JSON response in the console. However, I am unable to access any data from it.

A sample code segment is:

```
require(httr)

    target <- '#trump'
    sentence<- 'Donald trump has a wonderful toupe, it really is quite stunning that a man can be so refined and elegant'
    query <- url_encode(sentence)
    target <- gsub('#', '', target)
    endpoint <- "https://alchemy.p.mashape.com/text/TextGetTargetedSentiment?outputMode=json&target="
    apiCall <- paste(endpoint, target, '&text=', query, sep = '')

    resp <-GET(apiCall, add_headers("X-Mashape-Key" = sentimentKey, "Accept" = "application/json"))

    stop_for_status(resp)
    headers(resp)
    str(content(resp))
    content(resp, "text")
```

I followed examples in the httr quickstart guide from CRAN ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/quickstart.html)) as well as [this stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30382196/use-mashape-with-r).

Unfortunately, I keep getting either "unused parameters 'text' in content()" or "no definition exists for content() accepting a class of 'response.' Does anyone have any advice? PS the headers will print, and resp$content will print the raw bitstream

Comment: Maybe R is picking the wrong `content()` function? Have you tried `httr::content(resp, "text")`?

Comment: You need to set the `type=...` argument of ``content(...)` to `"application/json", as in `content(resp, type="application/json")`. In future, provide a reproducible example. You code does not run because you never define `sentimentkey`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expanding on the comment, you need to set the content type explicitly in the call to `content(...)`. Since your code is not reproducible, here is an example using the Census Bureau's geocoder (which returns a json response).

```
library(httr)
url <- "http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/onelineaddress"
resp <-GET(url, query=list(address="1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC",
                           benchmark=9,
                           format="json"))

json <- content(resp, type="application/json")
json$result$addressMatches[[1]]$coordinates
# $x
# [1] -77.038025
# 
# $y
# [1] 38.898735
```

Assuming your are actually getting a json response, and that it is well-formed, simply using `content(resp, type="application/json")` should work.

Comment: Thank you! This worked, although I did also have to incorporate lukeA's suggestion of specifically referencing httr by:
`json <- httr::content(resp, type ="application/json")`

Also thanks for the advice to include reproducible code