# Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'content' applied to an object of class "response" in R-Shiny

Tags: r, api, shiny, token

In R, I am able to run the following code to retrieve the API Token,

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
r <- POST("https://XXXXXXX.com/authservice/connect/token",
          config = list(),
          body = list(
            grant_type    = "password",
            username      = "testco",
            client_id     = "ClientIDname",
            client_secret = "Clientpassword",
            scope         = "xxxGroup"
          ),
          encode = "form"
)
warn_for_status(r)
status_code(r)
tok <- content(r)$access_token
```

When I run the same code in R-Shiny,

```
library(shiny)
library("httr")
library("rjson")

ui <- fluidPage(
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  r <- POST("https://XXXXXXX.com/authservice/connect/token",
            config = list(),
            body = list(
              grant_type    = "password",
              username      = "testco",
              client_id     = "ClientIDname",
              client_secret = "Clientpassword",
              scope         = "xxxGroup"
            ),
            encode = "form"
  )
  warn_for_status(r)
  status_code(r)
  tok <- content(r)$access_token
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I got the following error:

Error in UseMethod: no applicable method for 'content' applied to an object of class "response".

I noticed that the token is in R-Shiny variable r, but it just cannot be extracted by running tok <- content(r)$access_token

Following R and R-Shiny codes show similar error I described above:

[1] R-Code, is working

```
library("httr")
library("rjson")
api.url <- "http://api.tvmaze.com/lookup/shows?imdb=tt1325113"
r <- GET(api.url)

content(r)
```

[2] R-Shiny Code, returns the similar error:

```
library(shiny)
library("httr")
library("rjson")

ui <- fluidPage(
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  api.url <- "http://api.tvmaze.com/lookup/shows?imdb=tt1325113"
  r <- GET(api.url)
  content(r)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Does someone knows what is the problem? Any input is greatly apprecaited.

r2evans reminded me that the above code cannot produce the issue. I rechecked my code, and find the coding part caused the issue:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library("httr")
library("rjson")
library(jsonlite)

library(NLP)

ui <- fluidPage(
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  api.url <- "http://api.tvmaze.com/lookup/shows?imdb=tt1325113"
  r <- GET(api.url)
  tcont <- content(r)
  # tcont <- httr::content(r)
  t<-1
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If I add the library(NLP), it will caused the problem. The solutuion is
tcont <- httr::content(r).  Thanks again.

Comment: Using your last code-block, I cannot produce an error. To verify it, I added `observe({browser();1;})` to the server component, ran the app, and was able to verify that `api.url` and `r` were both defined (and the current tweet in its content has a `$summary` that starts with `"<p><b>Childrens Hospital</b> explores...`).

Comment: Hi r2evans, thanks for checking. I reran the last code-block, sometimes I got error, sometimes, as you said, it worked.  I am checking why it is not stable, probably I ran some other R-Shiny codes before I ran the testing code? I am checing now and narrow down the problematic part. I will keep you updated.  Thanks again.

Comment: To be honest, I'm a little confused why that's in the server-block and not within a `reactive` or `observe` block. I don't know that that'll make it more stable, but from an app-design viewpoint, it seems odd to load dynamic data at the session start with no ability to update it.

Comment: Hi r2evans, I think I get the reproducing code here:    Sorry I am not able to copy/paste the code in the comment block here. So I just edit my question to show the coding part that caused the problem. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The only difference I see is assigning the content to `tcont` and a static `t <- 1`, no other differences. Am I missing something? Or is it just an inconsistent-failure thing?

Comment: Hi r2evans, sorry for the confusion. The only difference is between with and without the NLP library.  The one with NLP will cause the problem. I am guessing there is a conflict of calling content() when we have both httr amnd NLP in the code. So replacing  "content(r)" with "httr::content(r)" specify the correct libraby to use and solve the problem.    BTW, I used "t<-1" for debugging and I fotgot to delete it. Sorry for the confusion it caused.   Thanks again for your help, r2evans!

Comment: Hi r2evans, I just realized your comment of "I don't know that that'll make it more stable, but from an app-design viewpoint, it seems odd to load dynamic data at the session start with no ability to update it.".---- yes, the code was in an observe block, but I just simply showed the coding part that caused the problem. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I see now. Yes, if you load `NLP` *after* `httr`, then `httr::content` will be masked. The use of `httr::content` sounds like a reasonable mitigation strategy. (This happens frequently with `dplyr::filter` versus `stats::filter`, fyi.)

Comment: Hi r2evans, may I ask you another question. I ran the following code  library(httr)
url <- "http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/onelineaddress"
resp <-GET(url, query=list(address="1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC",
                           benchmark=9,
                           format="json"))
 I got error:   Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Send failure: Connection was aborted       Any idea on what is the issue?

Comment: The code was originally posted by jlhoward here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617375/httr-get-operation-unable-to-access-json-response?rq=1.   

---- Sorry for the bad formatting. I don't how to format my content in the comment block here. Thanks!

Comment: (1) *"Connection was aborted"* could be several things but seems unlikely to be related to the R code itself. Perhaps firewalls, routing problems, momentary/temporary network glitches, or something else. (2) Code in comments: yup, the best you can do is use single backticks around them, and since newlines are not preserved, it is helpful to include semicolons between expressions. For example (and I'm adding another backtick to demonstrate explicitly): `\`library(httr); url <- "geocoding..."; resp <- GET(url, query=...);\``.

Comment: Hi r2evans, thanks for your comments and pointing to me the possible reasons of the error. And thank you very much for explaining on the coding in the comments. I really appreciate it!