# Question on Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) in R

Tags: r, api, url, httr

Question: I try running the following code, but got an error.

Code:

```
library(httr)
url <- "http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/onelineaddress"
resp <-GET(url, query=list(address="1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC",
                           benchmark=9,
                           format="json"))

json <- content(resp, type="application/json")
json$result$addressMatches[[1]]$coordinates
```

Error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

The original code was provided by jlhoward, linked here [httr GET operation unable to access JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33617375/httr-get-operation-unable-to-access-json-response)

Since I don't have enough reputation to directly ask my question in the comment block, I create this new post and hope someone can help with. Can someone help to take a look? Your input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. The protocol has changed to https from http (hence your error)
2. The benchmark options have changed (at least in terms of the option codes)

Current benchmarks are:

1. 4 for Public_AR_Current
2. 8 for Public_AR_ACS2021
3. 2020 for Public_AR_Census2020

An example update would thus look like:

```
library(httr)

url <- "https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/onelineaddress"
resp <-GET(url, query=list(address="1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington DC",
                           benchmark=8,
                           format="json"))
json <- content(resp, type="application/json")
json$result$addressMatches[[1]]$coordinates
```

Comment: Hi QHarr,  thanks for pointing me the http porblem. Yes, https works. Also thank you for letting me know the updates of the benchmark codes. I really appreciate it!

Comment: you are most welcome